# jQuery Simple Dropdown Menu need to close when click the same Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have simple jquery dropdown with below code. It's working properly. When I click the menu, ex: Projects then the dropdown will show. Now I need to close the dropdown when I click again the Projects then if I click again it will show the dropdown. Is there any way how to do that?

```js
$(".dropdown-toggle").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  $(".dropdown-menu").removeClass("active");
  $(this).siblings(".dropdown-menu").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 10rem;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    padding: .5rem 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-menu.active {
  visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="projects">Projects</a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu anim-1" data-target="projects">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">ABC</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">DEF</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="products">Products</a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu anim-1" data-target="products">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">GHI</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">JKL</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">MNO</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter the `$(".dropdown-menu")` before remove `.active`

```js
$(".dropdown-menu").not(menu).removeClass("active");
```

```js
$(".dropdown-toggle").on("click", function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  const menu = $(this).siblings(".dropdown-menu");
  $(".dropdown-menu").not(menu).removeClass("active");
  menu.toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 10rem;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    padding: .5rem 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-menu.active {
  visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="projects">Projects</a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu anim-1" data-target="projects">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">ABC</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">DEF</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="products">Products</a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu anim-1" data-target="products">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">GHI</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">JKL</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">MNO</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option if you're using jQuery would be to use toggleClass() which will add or remove "active" class depending on it's presence.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp